# About printf \t in the "C Programming A Modern Approach 2nd Edition"

Tags: c, printf

When I try to run this code it shows 2 TAB before `Price` in the first line of code, which I think is supposed to be only 1 TAB (4 Bytes).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("Item\tUnit\tPurchase\n\tPrice\tDate\n");
printf("Item\tUnit\tPurchase\nPrice\tDate\n");

return 0;
}
```

result:

[image]

In fact this code originate from the textbook
 `C Programming A Modern Approach 2nd Edition` by `King K.N`
Page 41 Section `"Escape Sequences"`.

I wonder if King K.N also use eclipse.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code...assuming this is what you want to do.

Comment: The result is fine. What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: In almost all normal terminals and command line environments, a tab character is *eight* spaces.

Comment: If you want 4 spaces, use 4 spaces.

Comment: It is eclipse, goto Window| Preferences | Run/Debug | Console | Display Tab Width and set it to 4 http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Frun-debug%2Fref-console.htm

Comment: @IvanIvanov but why the other TAB takes up 4 bytes normal only this one takes 8 bytes?

Comment: The tab character advances to the next tab stop, it doesn't insert N characters.

Comment: generally, if no special tab stops defined, the '\t' will advance the cursor to the next tab stop.  the tab stops default (for historical reasons) to column 9, column 17, column 25 ...  I.E. every 8 columns with the first at column 9

Comment: @Lee William it finishes gathering 8 characters, so if you put 7, it will add 1 space, if you put 4, it will add 4 spaces, if you put 11, it will add 5 extra spaces.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but why only this TAB takes up 8 bytes?

Comment: Because the terminal have tab *stops* every eight place, a tab goes to the next stop, and if you print three non-space characters followed by a tab, then the tab ads five characters to go to the next stop. Think of the terminal line as a ruler, with larger markings on the 10 cm, 20 cm, 30 cm and so on. A tab-stop is like those 10cm markings, they are at a fixed position on the ruler/terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab character is always one byte, in ASCII, with a value of 9.

Its interpretation is defined by the text renderer, not the language standard, the compiler, the OS, etc. Typically it advances the cursor to a multiple of some N. The most common choices for N are 4 or 8, but that doesn't mean the tab takes 4 bytes.

Some text editors replace tabs with spaces. Insertion of a tab might result in a file size increase of 4 bytes, but those bytes are spaces, not tabs.

You can't rely on tabs being formatted in any particular way, unless you can guarantee that the program's output will be displayed using a particular viewer in a certain configuration. If you need space characters instead, use space characters and don't use tabs as a shortcut.